# "If value exists in table" - Is there such a thing?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm new to mysql and I need some help.
I want to select all the rows from a table where a value exists, but not select that value:

For example:

```
ID           ITEM
--------------------
1             AA
1            22S
1             AB
2            F45
2             BB
3             1
3             1
3             AA
3            F45
3            F67
3             A
......
```

something like: SELECT ID, ITEM FROM TABLE1 IF Item "AA" is present except "AA"
and that would return:

```
1  225,AB
3  1,1,F45,F67,A
```

What is the actual query for doing this? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the list using `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT ID, group_concat(case when ITEM <> 'AA' then ITEM end)
FROM TABLE1 
group by id
having sum(item = 'AA') > 0;
```

The `case` statement ensures that the value is not included in the final list.  `group_concat()` ignores `NULL` values.

The `having` clause makes sure that there is at least one `'AA'` value for the returned row.

EDIT:

Thanks to Praveen:

**[Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de62ba/1)**

Comment: Ah, much better solution than mine :)

Comment: @hjpotter92: Actually AFAIK this is a worse solution because `HAVING` means that any indexes on `item` cannot be used to speed up this query. But I may be wrong.

Comment: thank you! can I also use this for regular expressions, like "case when ITEM <> LIKE 'AA%'" or something like that?

Comment: @user2578185 . . . Yes, the comparison logic can be anything acceptable boolean logic.

Answer (score 1):

This query will give you a list of ids that are associated with the AA item:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(id) FROM table WHERE item = 'AA'
```

You can use it as a subquery (embed it into a larger query) to get the desired result by considering only rows with ids that have an AA item, except those that have the AA item themselves:

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(item) FROM table
WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT(id) FROM table WHERE item = 'AA')
  AND item != 'AA'
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tbl.id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(tbl.item) AS item
FROM tbl
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id,
        item
    FROM tbl
    WHERE item = 'AA'
) tmp ON
    tmp.id = tbl.id
WHERE item <> 'AA'
```

Try the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Here, 'id' appears to be a foreign key to another table (since id usually implies identity). If you have such a table the the data you seek is returned by:

```
SELECT y.id, y.item
FROM yourtable y
INNER JOIN othertable o
ON y.id=o.id
INNER JOIN yourtable a
ON a.id=o.id
WHERE a.item='AA'
AND y.item<>'AA'
```

But this will return multiple rows (e.g. 2 entries for id 1 - 1,225 and 1,AB). To consolidate the results into a single line (usually very bad practice - sionce the result set is not reusable in queries):

```
SELECT y.id, GROUP_CONCAT(y.item)
FROM yourtable y
INNER JOIN othertable o
ON y.id=o.id
INNER JOIN yourtable a
ON a.id=o.id
WHERE a.item='AA'
AND y.item<>'AA'
GROUP BY y.id
```

If you don't have another table, then it's still possible by recreating a represnetation of the missing table:

```
SELECT y.id, GROUP_CONCAT(y.item)
FROM yourtable y
INNER JOIN (
     SELECT DISTINCT a.id
     FROM yourtable a
     WHERE a.item='AA'
) o
ON y.id=o.id
WHERE y.item<>'AA'
GROUP BY y.id
```

BTW mixing different *types* of data in the same column is a bad idea too.